# Infinity time of compilation C++

Tags: c++, templates

I tried to implement a persistent deque structure. But I'm not very familiar with templates in C++. There is only a `push_front` function now and it does not compile properly.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template < typename T > class Container{
public:
    T val;
    Container(){}
    Container(T _val){
        val = _val;
    }
};

template < typename T > class Deque{
public:
    Container<T>* head;
    Container<T>* tail;
    Deque< pair<T, T> > *child;
    Deque<T>(){}
    Deque<T>(Container<T>* _head, Deque< pair<T, T> > *_child, Container<T>* _tail){
        head = _head;
        child = _child;
        tail = _tail;
    }
    Deque<T>* push_front(T x){
        if (this == NULL)
            return new Deque<T>(new Container<T>(x), NULL, NULL);
        if (head == NULL)
            return new Deque<T>(new Container<T>(x), child, tail);
        return new Deque<T>(NULL, child->push_front(make_pair(x, head->val)), tail);
    }
};

int main(){
    Deque<int> d;
    int a = 1;
    d.push_front(a);
}
```

There are scheme of algorithm of push_front function.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/an1xd.jpg

Comment: Could you describe your problem some more? What error are you seeing? What did you expect to see?

Comment: There are no errors. Just compiller works infinity.
I can't call function recursively with other type of argument.

Comment: what compiler are you using? Looks fine to me: http://ideone.com/hRsJRJ.  EDIT: ooops, it doesn't I have missed the full `main` implementation, like here: http://ideone.com/aZjKAW

Comment: Try to call d.push_front
Compilers g++ and visual c++ 2010

Comment: Yes, this doesn't finish compiling for me under gcc-4.7.2 or clang-3.2.

Comment: Tried on Visual C++ 2010, doesn't finish compilation. Enabling verbose doesn't yield much info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the compiler might be confused by the fact that `Deque<int>` has a `child` of type `Deque<pair<int,int>>*` which has a `child` of type `Deque<pair<pair<int, int>, pair<int, int> > >*` which has a child of .... ad infinitum, and tries to instantiate all these types.

```
Deque<int>
    child: Deque<pair<int, int> >*
        child: Deque<pair<pair<int, int> , pair<int, int> > >*
            child: Deque<pair<pair<pair<int, int>....
```

Comment: There must be something to above construct then which prevents this from hitting a maximal recursion depth.

Comment: @honk, there is: available memory :)  compiler will just puke after some time.

Comment: Thinking a little more about this there doesn't seem to be recursion here. But all the definitions should fill up the available memory at some point.

Comment: sure, there is no recursion in sense of program execution, but there is in sense that compiler recursively finds new types to instantiate

Comment: I think I see now. With recursion I was referring to recursively defined template types which at some point typically trigger a compile-time error when going beyond a specific recursion depth. The issue here seems to be that there is really only one type being defined so that limit doesn't seem to matter. Still surprising none of the compilers mentioned here is able to catch that behavior.

Comment: If delete last string from push_front function, all compiles properly.

Comment: you mean last line, right? might be, as you remove the only place where a `child` instance is created, so the compiler doesn't have to instantiate the `child`'s type

Answer (score 0):

You have a recursive instantiation:

```
dt.cpp: In instantiation of 'Deque<T>::Deque(Container<T>*, Deque<std::pair<T, T> >*,
Container<T>*) [with T = std::pair<std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int> >,
std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int> > >]':
dt.cpp:38:83:   recursively required from 'Deque<T>* Deque<T>::push_front(T) [with T = 
std::pair<int, int>]'
```

And so on. If you make some minor modifications to `Deque`, `g++` will start spitting out these errors:

```
Deque<T>(Container<T>* head_, Deque< pair<T, T> > *child_, Container<T>* tail_)
  : head(head_), child(child_), tail(tail_)
{ }

Deque<T>* push_front(T x)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return new Deque<T>(new Container<T>(x), child, tail);
    return new Deque<T>(NULL, child->push_front(make_pair(x, head->val)), tail);
}
```